# Bug in pygame when collidereacting

Tags: python, pygame

I can't collide rect whit rectangles, should I give up or try using x and y positions?
I don't get any errors from it but it closes right after i run it.
can you please suggest me what to do.

```
    import pygame,sys,time,random
    
    pygame.init()
    
    x = 425
    y = 750
    player_x = x/2-25
    player_y = 600
    player_speed = 0
    timer = 0
    score = 0
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    enemy_x = random.randint(0,425)
    enemy_y = -(random.randint(0,500))
    enemy2_x = random.randint(0,425)
    enemy2_y = -(random.randint(0,500))
    police_x = random.randint(0,425)
    police_y = random.randint(750,1400)
    police2_x = random.randint(0,425)
    police2_y = random.randint(750,1400)
    enemy_speed = 16
    police_speed = 3
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",50)
    player = pygame.image.load("macchina.png").convert_alpha()
    pygame.display.set_caption("NapoliSimulator (schiva le buche e non farti prendere dalla pula)")
    
    def player_a():
        global player_x,player_y,player_speed
        player_x+=player_speed
        player = pygame.image.load("macchina.png").convert_alpha()
        screen.blit(player,(player_x,player_y))
    def enemy_a():
        global enemy_x,enemy_y,enemy_speed,enemy2_x,enemy2_y,enemy3_x,enemy3_y,enemy4_x,enemy4_y,enemy5_x,enemy5_y
        enemy_y += enemy_speed
        enemy2_y += enemy_speed
        enemy = pygame.image.load("crepa.png").convert_alpha()
        enemy_2 = pygame.image.load("crepa.png").convert_alpha()
        screen.blit(enemy,(enemy_x,enemy_y))
        screen.blit(enemy,(enemy2_x,enemy2_y))
    def enemy_b():
        global police_x,police_y,police_speed,police2_x,police2_y
        police_y -= police_speed
        police = pygame.image.load("polizia.png").convert_alpha()
        screen.blit(police,(police_x,police_y))
    
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player_speed -= 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player_speed += 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player_speed += 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player_speed -= 5
    
        screen.fill((200,200,200))
    
        player_a()
    
        if enemy_y >= 700:
            enemy_y = -(random.randint(500,1200))
            enemy_x = random.randint(0,425)
            score += 1
        if enemy2_y >= 700:
            enemy2_y = -(random.randint(0,750))
            enemy2_x = random.randint(0,425)
            score += 1
        if police_y <= 40:
            police_y = random.randint(750,1900)
            police_x = random.randint(0,425)
            score += 1
    
        enemy_a()
    
        if score >= 7:
            enemy_b()
    
        if score >= 15:
            police_speed += 0.0001
    
        enemy = pygame.image.load("crepa.png").convert_alpha()
        enemy_2 = pygame.image.load("crepa.png").convert_alpha()
        police = pygame.image.load("polizia.png").convert_alpha()
    
        playerr = player.get_rect()
        enemyr = enemy.get_rect()
        policer = police.get_rect()
        enemyr2 = enemy_2.get_rect()
    
        if enemyr.colliderect(playerr):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if enemyr2.colliderect(playerr):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if crepar.colliderect(policer):
            enemy_b()
        if player.colliderect(policer):
            pygame.quit()
            ys.exit()
    
        pygame.display.flip()
    
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: This is not a bug in pygame. It is a bug in your application.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top left of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`:

```py
playerr = player.get_rect(topleft = (player_x, player_y))
enemyr = enemy.get_rect(topleft = (enemy_x, enemy_y))
policer = police.get_rect(topleft = (police_x, police_y))
enemyr2 = enemy_2.get_rect(topleft = (enemy2_x, enemy2_y))

if enemyr.colliderect(playerr):
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
if enemyr2.colliderect(playerr):
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
if player.colliderect(policer):
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```